# Loading JavaFX GUI in background

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently trying to create a Splash Screen for my program since it takes some time to start up.
The problem is that it takes a while to create the GUI (creating dialogues, updating tables etc.). And I can't move the GUI creation to a background thread (like the "Task" class), since I'll get an "Not on FXApplication Thread" exception.
I tried using:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
             //create GUI
  }
}
```

And the "call" method of a Task:

```
public class InitWorker extends Task<Void> {

    private Model model;
    private ViewJFX view;

    public InitWorker(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
          View view = new View();
          Collection collection = new Collection();
          //do stuff
    }
}
```

When I wrote the program in Swing I could just display and update the Splash Screen on the EventDispatchThread, without any real concurreny. The code looked like this:

```
public void build() {
        MainOld.updateProgressBar(MainOld.PROGRESSBAR_VALUE++, "Creating Menus");
        menuCreator = new MenuCreatorOld (model, this);
        menuCreator.createMenu();
        MainOld.updateProgressBar(MainOld.PROGRESSBAR_VALUE, "Creating Toolbar");
        toolBar = menuCreator.createToolBar();

        createWesternPanelToolBar();

        shoppingPanel = new ShoppingListOld(model, this, collectionController, shoppingController, controller);

        centerTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
            MainOld.updateProgressBar(MainOld.PROGRESSBAR_VALUE++, "Creating Collection");
            collectionPanel = new CollectionOld(model, collectionController, this, controller);
            MainOld.updateProgressBar(MainOld.PROGRESSBAR_VALUE++, "Creating Wish List");
            wishPanel = new WishListOld(model, this, collectionController, wishController, controller);

            MainOld.updateProgressBar(MainOld.PROGRESSBAR_VALUE++, "Creating Folders Table");
             //and so on
}

public static void updateProgressBar(int progressValue, String text) {
    System.out.println("Loading Bar Value:"+progressValue);
    progressBar.setValue(progressValue);
    loadingLabel.setText(text);
    progressBar.setString(text);
}
```

**Is there any way to create the GUI in the background while displaying a Splash Screen with a loading bar?**

Edit:

I had a look at my code and was able to decrease the startup time by 5 seconds. Most of the dialogs pull data from the database when they are created. So I moved the creation of the dialogs into their getter methods. That resulted in an improvement of 3 seconds. But I would still like to know if there is in a way to create the GUI on a background thread.

Edit:

As suggested, I also tried using "RunLater" in a "Task".
This way I can create the GUI and display the SplashScreen, but I can't update the progress bar and progress label, since the GUI creation blocks the JavaFX application thread. The progress bar and label are only updated, after the GUI has been fully created.

Here's an example you guys can run (I removed the splash screen and only kept the progress bar and progress label):

```
public class InitWorker extends Task<Void> {


    private static ProgressBar progressBar;
    private static Label progressLabel;
    private static double PROGRESS_MAX = 5; 
    private double loadingValue;

    public InitWorker() {
        loadingValue = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded() {
        System.out.println("Succeeded");
    }

    @Override
    protected void failed() {
        System.out.println("Failed");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("RUNNING");
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                displaySplashScreen();
                for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    updateProgressBar(loadingValue++, "Label "+i);
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    Label label = new Label("Label " + i);
                    VBox panel = new VBox();
                    panel.getChildren().add(label);
                    Scene scene = new Scene(panel);
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.centerOnScreen();
                    stage.show();
                }
//              updateProgressBar(1, "Initializing...");

            }});

        return null;
    }


    public void updateProgressBar(double loadingValue, String text) {
        progressBar.setProgress(loadingValue / PROGRESS_MAX);
        progressLabel.setText(text);
    }




    public static void displaySplashScreen() {

        Stage progressBarStage = new Stage();
        progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        Scene progressBarScene = new Scene(progressBar);
        progressBarStage.setScene(progressBarScene);

        Stage progressLabelStage = new Stage();
        progressLabel = new Label("Loading...");
        progressLabel.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        progressLabel.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
        Scene progressLabelScene = new Scene(progressLabel);
        progressLabelStage.setScene(progressLabelScene);

        double progressBarWidth = 500;
        double progressBarHeight = 75;

        //muss angezeigt werden, um sie abhängig von Größe zu positionieren
        progressBarStage.show();
        progressLabelStage.show();
        //

        progressBarStage.setWidth(progressBarWidth);
        progressBarStage.setHeight(progressBarHeight);
        progressBarStage.centerOnScreen();
        progressBarStage.centerOnScreen();
        progressLabelStage.setY(progressLabelStage.getY() + 25);


    }

}
```

Comment: It shouldn't take any appreciable time to create the GUI. It might take time to retrieve data, etc, that you are going to display in the GUI, but you can do that part on the background thread. Are you sure it is the actual GUI creation that is time-consuming?

Comment: I had a look at my code and was able to decrease the startup time by 5 seconds. Most of the dialogs pull data from the database when they are created. So I moved the creation of the dialogs into their getter methods. That resulted in an improvement of 3 seconds. But I would still like to know if there is in general a way to create the GUI in a background thread.

Comment: What hardware and OS are you using? Can you provide a [mcve] exhibiting the issue?

Comment: Added example code to my original post. I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

See [Task documentation titled "A Task Which Modifies The Scene Graph"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), which provides an example:

```
final Group group = new Group();
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            if (isCancelled()) break;
            final Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 10);
            r.setX(10 * i);
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    group.getChildren().add(r);
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

The above example add the rectangles to the scene graph via a 100 runLater calls.  A more efficient way to do this would be to add the rectangles to a group not attached to the active scene graph, then only add the group to the active scene graph in the runLater call.  For example:

```
final Group groupInSceneGraph = new Group();
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {
        final Group localGroup = new Group();
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            if (isCancelled()) break;
            final Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 10);
            r.setX(10 * i);

            localGroup.getChildren().add(r);
        }

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                groupInSceneGraph.add(localGroup);
            }
        });

        return null;
    }
};
```

You can create and modify most scene graph objects off of the JavaFX application thread (including loading FXML), as long as the objects aren't attached to the active scene graph.  By active scene graph I mean a scene graph which is currently attached as a scene to a displayed stage.  (A complicated control such as a `WebView` may be an exception to this rule and may require creation on the JavaFX application thread).

You must only attach the scene graph objects created off of the JavaFX application thread to the active scene graph on the JavaFX application thread (for example using `Platform.runLater()`). And, you must work with them on the JavaFX application thread as long they continue to be attached to the active scene graph.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried this method. This way I can display the Splash Screen and create the GUI, but I can't update the progress bar. See my original post for example code.